# Как снизить нагрузку на ЦП при использовании ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, многопоточность

В общем: есть `websocket` сервер, в него приходят запросы, которые я обрабатываю и складываю ответы в очередь (LinkedBlockingQueue).

Обработкой ответов занимается класс `ResponseExecutor`. Так как он работает с блокирующей очердью, данным способом получается снизить нагрузку на ЦП в моменты когда очередь пуста, т.к.  метод `.take()` блокирует поток, но когда в очереди накапливается много ответов - то их обработка может длится долгое время, потому что не все потоки задействованы. Вот код класса `ResponseExecutor`:

```
public class ResponseExecutor {

    private static final String TAG = ResponseExecutor.class.getSimpleName();
    private Log log = new Log(TAG, false);

    private final static int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 16;

    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<ResponseValue> queue;
    private ConcurrentHashMap<ServiceUser, CopyOnWriteArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper>> users;

    public ResponseExecutor(ConcurrentHashMap<ServiceUser, CopyOnWriteArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper>> users, LinkedBlockingQueue<ResponseValue> queue) {
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE, new ExecutorThreadFactory());
        this.users = users;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    public void processResponse(ResponseValue response) {
        this.queue.add(response);
        this.executorService.execute(new Consumer(this.users, this.queue));
    }

    private class Consumer implements Runnable {

        private ConcurrentHashMap<ServiceUser, CopyOnWriteArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper>> users;
        private LinkedBlockingQueue<ResponseValue> queue;

        public Consumer(ConcurrentHashMap<ServiceUser, CopyOnWriteArrayList<WSDeviceSessionWrapper>> users, LinkedBlockingQueue<ResponseValue> queue) {
            this.users = users;
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    ResponseValue value = queue.take();
                    process(value);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Я хочу вместо `LinkedBlockingQueue` использовать `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` но она съедает `ЦП` в моменты когда очередь пуста.

**Вопрос**: можно ли каким то образом использовать `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` и сделать так, что бы цикл `while` работал только когда в очереди есть данные?

**P.S.** была мысль прерывать все потоки после того как очередь стала пустой, но пока не до конца понял как это реализовать.

Comment: Попробуйте механизм мониторов (wait/notify). Пусть если очередь пуста, то поток засыпает на `wait()`. Как только добавится элемент, пробуждайте поток `notify()` и делайте свой `take()` и `process()`.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov можно небольшой пример, как это реализуется?

Comment: Пожалуйста: http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/notify-and-wait-example/

Comment: По-моему, вы странное делаете. В вызове `processResponse` добавляется ответ в очередь и бесконечное задание в экзекутор. Поскольку пул фиксированного размера, больше 16 заданий выполняться не будет и кончится память. Я бы убрал очередь совсем, оставил только экзекутор и добавлял в него `new Consumer(this.users, response)`.

Comment: @zRrr  если убрать мою очередь и добавлять просто Consumer то они тоже будут складываться в блокирующую очередь которая находится в самом Executor и которую ему можно задать через конструктор ThreadPoolExecutor, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Меня тоже посещала мысль что этот участок кода ошибочный, я реньше просто запускал метод .execute() 16 раз и все, потом эти потоки просто слушали очередь.

Comment: Да, метод `processResponse` выглядит сомнительно. Шаблон использования блокирующих очередей обычно подразумевает, что есть некоторое нефиксированное количество производителей и некоторое фиксированное количество потребителей. При этом обычно потребителей гораздо меньше, чем производителей. Количество потребителей также может изменяться пропорционально нагрузке. У вас же всегда соотношение 1 к 1. Не говоря уже о множестве создаваемых потребителей и постановке их в очередь.